# How many SQL-connections they are recommended in a project PHP ? What is the ideal number of SQL-connections?

Tags: php, pdo

I work now on a project for learning i'm a beginner, i use singelton pattern to make sure, that there is just one PDO connection to the Data Base.
I made var_dump() for all possible connections to the Mysql and I founded that there were 10 objects of pdo.
how can i found, from where come all this objects?

Are 10 objects of PDO normal?
I wanted to use just one for all the project.

my singelton

```
<?php
namespace App\Database;
use PDO;
use PDOException;

class DataBase
{
     private static $instance;
     private PDO $pdo;
     private function __construct()
    {
      try {
        $db= parse_ini_file("..//..//..//config.ini");
        #$db= parse_ini_file("..//..//config.ini");
        $type = $db['type'];
        $host = $db['host'];
        $name = $db['name'];
        $user = $db['user'];
        $password = $db['password'];
        $this->pdo = new PDO($type . ':host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $name, $user, $password);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "there is an error";
        die();
      }
      $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
      return $this->pdo;
    }

 private function __clone() {}

 public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!static::$instance) {
        static::$instance = new DataBase();
    }
        return static::$instance;
    }

 public function getPdo(): PDO
  {
      return $this->pdo;
  }

}

?>
```

then I made a connection of the pdo like this in another place, where I need to use pdo init.

```
  function makePdo(){
    $db= DataBase::getInstance();
    $pdo= $db->getPdo();
    var_dump($pdo);
    return $pdo;
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that these are 10 different PDO objects? I suspect that they are all references to the same object.

Comment: Please share your code to how you implemented your singleton.

Comment: i become this result when I make var_dump 
`object(PDO)#10 (0) { } object(PDO)#10 (0) { } object(PDO)#10 (0) { } `

Comment: you can see now my singelton in the post @apokryfos

Comment: what mean the number 10 and 0?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's multiple instances created with this code.

Comment: what mean the number #10 and (0)? @apokryfos

Comment: #10 looks like an object identifier. It probably means this is the 10th (or 11th) object PHP allocated, however the other objects were probably not PDO objects

Answer (score 0):

10 connections are not normal, you should have only one to one DB. Use singleton pattern for database connection:

https://gist.github.com/jonashansen229/4534794
https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php

In this case, you will have one connection and always will get it instead of creating duplicates.

Comment: can you see my singelton please ? i edited my code with my singelton, which i used it already.

thx

Comment: @BasharIT __coustructor is a `:void` function it couldn't return anything
All other things are look correct and it should work. You can call your `makePdo() `function twice and compare the result, it should be the same object.
`
$a = makePdo();
$b = makePdo();
if ($a === $b) {
    var_dump("SAME");
} else {
    var_dump("NOT SAME");
}
`

Answer (score 0):

No it should be only one object, the best way to implment it, is to create a separate config file to store your DBMS credentials as associative array, like mysql db_name, host .. etc.
Then create a config class to get those values by creating a static get method.
and finally use this get method inside your db constructor to get the credentials.
I'm pretty sure If you do that you'll get only one instance of PDO object.

Comment: i made then the connection like this in another place, where I need to use the pdo
is this right?
`function makePdo(){
    $db= DataBase::getInstance();
    $pdo= $db->getPdo();
    var_dump($pdo);
    return $pdo;
 }`

Comment: what mean the number #10 and (0)?